# Merging Data to single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two queries one is to get ISSUE and RETURN of Items from table.

```
select MATU.ITEMNUM ,
MATU.DESCRIPTION ,
MATU.STORELOC ,
MATU.CONDITIONCODE,
MATU.ISSUETYPE,
SUM(MATU.QUANTITY )as QUANTITY,
INV.MINLEVEL,
INV.MAXLEVEL
from MATUSETRANS MATU
LEFT OUTER JOIN Inventory INV
ON INV.ITEMNUM=MATU.ITEMNUM
AND INV.LOCATION=MATU.STORELOC
where MATU.ITEMNUM='H95-04-0010'  --A57-01-0459A
AND MATU.TRANSDATE >'01-JAN-19'
AND MATU.CONDITIONCODE='01' and MATU.STORELOC='09'
GROUP BY MATU.ITEMNUM ,MATU.DESCRIPTION ,MATU.STORELOC ,INV.MINLEVEL,INV.MAXLEVEL,MATU.PONUM ,MATU.ISSUETYPE,MATU.CONDITIONCODE;
```

Which result look like

[image]

And My second query is get TRANSFER IN and TRANSFER OUT Items from table

```
select ITEMNUM ,
DESCRIPTION,
TOSTORELOC ,
FROMSTORELOC ,
--TRANSDATE ,
sum(QUANTITY) as QUANTITY ,
ISSUE_CATEGORY as ISSUETYPE,LOCATION from
(select MATR.ITEMNUM,MATR.DESCRIPTION,MATR.TOSTORELOC,MATR.FROMSTORELOC,MATR.TRANSDATE,MATR.QUANTITY,MATR.ISSUETYPE,
        CASE WHEN INV.LOCATION = MATR.FROMSTORELOC THEN 'TRANSFER OUT'
             WHEN INV.LOCATION = MATR.TOSTORELOC THEN 'TRANSFER IN'
             ELSE '_'END as ISSUE_CATEGORY,
        MATR.DOCNUM,INV.LOCATION  
from MATRECTRANS MATR
INNER JOIN INVENTORY INV
ON INV.ITEMNUM=MATR.ITEMNUM 
where MATR.Itemnum='H95-04-0010' AND MATR.TRANSDATE>'01-JAN-19')
where ISSUE_CATEGORY in ('TRANSFER IN','TRANSFER OUT') and DOCNUM is not null and location='09'
group by ITEMNUM,DESCRIPTION ,TOSTORELOC ,FROMSTORELOC ,ISSUETYPE ,ISSUE_CATEGORY,LOCATION;
```

Which result look like

[image]

When I am trying to join both record look like, record are repeating!

[image]

How can i tackle this issue?

I need like this
[image]

If theres any TRANSFER IN/OUT values then show them else 0.

Comment: How are you trying to join them? And how do you want to join them?

Comment: I created view for both queries and joined them for result on STORELOC=LOCATION

Comment: It hard for us to help you since we don't know the table design but looking at the column names maybe you need to work with TOSTORELOC and FROMSTORELOC as well when joining and possible also ISSUETYPE/CATEGORY to determine how to join the location related columns